# How to store the sqlite3 database file in the Library directory of an app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes, file-sharing

Pretty much everyone and every tutorial seems to store it's private app data in the documents directory.

But in my image editing app I want the user to be able to use iTunes file sharing. The problem: It exposes everything in documents to the user, and he can accidentally delete important private app data folders like the SQLite database.

Apple recommends this:

> If you do not want files to be shared
>   with the user, put them in your
>   application’s Library directory. If
>   none of the standard Library
>   subdirectories are appropriate, create
>   a private directory inside the Library
>   directory and give it the name of your
>   application’s bundle ID. You can then
>   use that directory to store any files
>   that are private to your application.

I have never heard of that Library directory. Now the question is: How can I access this directory? Where is it? Will it be backed up, just like the documents directory when the user syncs with iTunes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSLibraryDirectory` in lieu of `NSDocumentDirectory` (in those examples you speak of) to get the library directory and then create a directory in there using `NSFileManager`.

Read [`this`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10) for more information on the application directory structure. The `Library` directory is backed up except the `Caches` directory.